# A question concerning group action and stabilizer.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions, stabilizer

I am trying to solve the problem:

Let
\begin{align*}
G \times X &\longrightarrow X \\
(g,x) &\longmapsto g \circ x
\end{align*}
be an action of $G$ on $X$. Suppose that $K \leq G$, and that the action of $K$ on
$X$
\begin{align*}
K \times X &\longrightarrow X \\
(k,x) &\longmapsto k \circ x
\end{align*}
obtained by restriction of the first variable is transitive.

Prove that if $g \in G$ and $x \in X$, then there exists $k \in K$ and $b \in
\operatorname{Stab}G(x)$ such that $g = kb$.

My thoughts are the following:
If the equality $g = kb$ holds, then
$g \circ x = (kb)\circ x = k\circ (b \circ x) = k \circ x$.
And how can I prove that those elements $k$ satisfying $k\circ x = g\circ x$ still belong to
$K$?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Somewhere, you have to use the hypothesis that the action of $K$ is transitive. So, what does transitive mean (in this context)?

Comment: Transitive means for any $x ,y\in X$, there exists $k \in K$ such that $k \circ x=y $.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't prove that if $g \circ x = k \circ x$ then $k \in K$, because it doesn't have to be in $K$. However, you are given that $K$ acts transitively on $X$. Can you use that to find $k \in K$ such that $g \circ x = k \circ x$? Once you find such $k$, you can see that

\begin{align}
k^{-1} \circ (g \circ x) &= k^{-1} \circ (k \circ x) \\
(k^{-1} g) \circ x &= (k^{-1} k) \circ x \\
(k^{-1} g) \circ x &= e \circ x \\
(k^{-1} g) \circ x &=  x.
\end{align}

So $b := k^{-1} g \in \text{Stab}_G (x)$ and $g = kb$.

Comment: I should treat $g \circ x \in X$ as $a$ and $x \in X$ as $b$. Then by the transitivity, there is $k \in K$ such that $k\circ b = a$. That is the desired $k$. Is this right?

Comment: @Villhaze Correct!